# If a condition is met then add to the previous row elseif subtract from the previous row in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, if-statement

I'm working on a problem where if certain conditions are met then I need to add or subtract from the previous row.
So I have the following df:

```py
data = {'sample_val':[5.5, 6.2 , 4.0, 7.8, 3.6], 'sample_lab':['nor','high','nor','high','low']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to add an additional column 'adjustment', that is filled by the following rules and has a starting value of 10:

- if sample_val < 4 then - 6 from the previous adjustment entry
- if 4<= sample_val <= 5 then +0 to the previous adjustment entry
- if sample_val>5 then add 4 to the previous adjustment entry

I've tried `iterrows( )`, but I can't get it to add or subtract.  I also tried `np.where`, but can't get it to iterate.

Comment: Please add the expected output

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to know which coefficients you must add or subtract, and then accumulate the result to the initial value of `10` using panda's [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
import numpy as np

x = df.sample_val.to_numpy()
adj = np.select([x<4, (x>=4)&(x<=5), x>5], [-6,0,4], x)
df['adjustment'] = 0
df.loc[0, 'adjustment'] = 10
df['adjustment'] = df.adjustment.add(adj).cumsum()
```

---

```
print(df)
   sample_val sample_lab  adjustment
0         5.5        nor        14.0
1         6.2       high        18.0
2         4.0        nor        18.0
3         7.8       high        22.0
4         3.6        low        16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to assign numbers to bins and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + 10 for the cumulated sum starting at 10:

```
df['adjustment'] = (pd.cut(df['sample_val'],
                           bins=[-np.inf, 4, 5, np.inf],
                           labels=[-6, 0, 4])
                      .astype(int)
                      .cumsum()
                   ) + 10
```

output:

```
   sample_val sample_lab  adjustment
0         5.5        nor          14
1         6.2       high          18
2         4.0        nor          12
3         7.8       high          16
4         3.6        low          10
```

Comment: The conditions are a continuous, of course. Nice use of pd.cut there!

Comment: @yatu yes of course, else I would also use `select` ;)